# HTML5 download attribute doesn't work, Forcing file rename on download

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express

I am trying for weeks to change the name of the file being downloaded. But still no luck. Instead of file name to be `Chrysanthemum.jpg`, it becomes the hash of the file, i.e. `241693260.jpg`

In my back-end I am using Node.js and Express.js to handle file upload/download. I am hashing the file name and attributes to make sure files are not getting overwritten.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="http://localhost:3000/getAttachments?name=Chrysanthemum.jpg&amp;type=image%2Fjpeg&amp;size=879394&amp;lastModified=1247549551674&amp;extension=jpg" download="Chrysanthemum.jpg" target="_blank">Download File</a>
```

Here is my back-end:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + "/uploads"));

app.get("/getAttachments", function (req, res) {
    try {
        var fileToBeSent = hashCode(req.query.name + req.query.type + req.query.size + req.query.lastModified + req.query.extension);
        fileToBeSent += req.query.extension  ? '.' + req.query.extension : '';

    // res.sendFile("./uploads/" + fileToBeSent, {
    //     root: __dirname,
    //     "Content-Disposition": '"attachment; filename="' + (req.query.extension  ? '.' + req.query.extension : '') + '"',
    //     "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    // });

        res.redirect("/uploads/" + fileToBeSent);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("an attempt to GET a file that doesn't exist.");
    }
});
```

**So as I am renaming the file name in my back-end**, I am trying to rename file back to it's original name using HTML5 but I am not being successful.

**UPDATE**: Using the express's sendFile result in the same issue.

**UPDATE**: My server is uses cross-origin

Comment: What browser are you using when attempting to test this. According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) IE and Safari still do not support this attribute...

Comment: Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @War10ck I think it is not a browser issue, it is a problem of HTML5's download attribute.

Comment: There are a few restrictions on this attribute's use according to MDN: _1. If the HTTP header Content-Disposition: is present and gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header has priority over this attribute._, _2. If this attribute is present and Content-Disposition: is set to inline, Firefox gives priority to Content-Disposition, like for the filename case, while Chrome gives priority to the download attribute._, _3. This attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin._. Are any of these the case?

Comment: you can fetch the file contents with ajax, and populate the href with a window.URL or dataURL. that way, the server's header config doesn't matter, and you get consistent cross-browser behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is to provide the entire file name that you want the file to be downloaded as. In your Content-Disposition it doesn't look like you were providing the entire filename.

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/uploads/" + fileToBeSent, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + req.query.name + '"'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem a year ago and spent a lot of time before found that this is potential problem of Chrome [Prove for version 35 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026009/2135140)
Avoiding repeating names you can use static id with increment. Hope this answer will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Re-renaming the file using Node JS, not HTML5 is your best bet.

[Renaming files using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504566/renaming-files-using-node-js)

Comment: Then how can I guarantee that two different files are not being renamed to the same name before getting downloaded and they will get overwritten by each other. This solution is problematic.

Comment: Would renaming the file to "Chrysanthemum_Hash" solve your problem, where _Hash is the existent hash?